# Which is correct? 1. for nagging me to apply; or 2. for nagging me into applying

Tags: verbs, sentence

Which is correct in the context of "special thanks to him":
1. for nagging me to apply; or 2. for nagging me into applying. 
If neither, let me know as other options also come to mind.

I recently posted a lovely photo from my citizenship ceremony, so this phrase was in reference to my brother as "also special thanks to my brother for successfully nagging me to apply"

Comment: Both work; the constructions differ, but mean more-or-less the same thing. (2) implies that you actually applied, and whereas (1) *can* mean that, it can also mean that he simply nagged unfruitfully. Because you haven't said what you want the sentence to mean, it's not possible to say more than that, really.

Comment: My apologies! I recently posted a lovely photo from my citizenship ceremony, so this phrase was in reference to my brother as "also special thanks to my brother for successfully nagging me to apply"

Comment: If it's obvious from the context that you have applied, then either will do. As you've edited your question, it's no longer unclear.

Comment: Yes, my original post with photo says exactly this: "Officially a Brit! This one's for my mum & dad. Also, special thanks to my brother for successfully nagging me to apply! Thanks for your swift replies. I also had a thought about "nagging AT me to apply"? Not certain however. The reason I ask, of course, is due to someone posting "*into applying" as a comment and wanted to clarify, as I do value the use of grammar!

Comment: No. A pain or a worry can nag at you; brothers (or indeed anyone else) just nag.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So I should take it that in the above context my phrase makes sense and is as acceptable as well as if would have used "into applying" instead? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Leach above is quite correct. The only salient difference is the outcome of his nagging. Because of the outcome his nagging you to apply was not enough but his nagging you into applying did the trick.

Congrats on your success wherever you are. Here I would have said don't mind the nagging. It's the American way.

Comment: "his nagging you to apply was not enough" Minor niggle: the nagging could still have been the deciding factor, but saying "nagging me to apply" simply doesn't imply it either way.

Comment: My niggle was that "Nagging To" was only Nagging Up To as in X < 1 but still not up to 1. This was not enough to be over the line as in X <= 1. But "Nagging into" did make it over the line.  As niggles go this is among the tiniest and has reached its climax here in the footnotes of the grammar website.

Comment: @Flater: I agree with your description of the niggle's magnitude but until they open an "English Language Niggle" site, soon I hope, such things will still fall to us to peck over.